# using C++ code in R

Tags: c++, r

I'm experimenting the Rcpp & inline packages to speed up my computation..
I want to know how to make C++ CODE (not a c++ function) work 
with these packages?

Here is an example I tried which consists of building a dynamic array called 'tableau' and display the result. I both tried the 'cppFunction' and 'cxxfunction' but no success... 
Can someone gives  me a hint?

```
require(inline);require(Rcpp)

src='vector < vector < int > > tableau (

{

{1,2,3,42},

{0,2,3},

{11,12}

}

);

return tableau;
'

cppFunction(src)
```

```
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
In addition: Warning message:
No function found for Rcpp::export attribute at file7bc1b0f5993.cpp:5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R` has no idea what to do with a `<vector <vector <int>>`. 
To return a list, you have to use the type `List` and `NumericVector`:

```
src = 'List tableau() {
  NumericVector v1 = NumericVector::create(1,2,3,42);
  NumericVector v2 = NumericVector::create(0,2,3);
  NumericVector v3 = NumericVector::create(11,12); 

  return List::create(v1, v2, v3);
}'
createTableau <- cppFunction(src)
createTableau()
## [[1]]
## [1]  1  2  3 42
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 0 2 3
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 11 12
```

You should really read at least some of the documentation. Here's a good place to start: [Rcpp Tutorial](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html)

Comment: We tend to prefer our own, more extensive documentation. It is also included in the package. And there is the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, I'm aware about the Rcpp documentation but some stuffs are just too technical for a non Computer Scientist like me as how to manipulate dataframe using Rcpp...

Comment: We all have to start somewhere! If you find yourself struggling with concepts, take a look at the Rcpp Gallery @DirkEddelbuettel linked above, that provides examples on how to implement different tasks in Rcpp, and you can always modify the code from there. Just be aware that writing C++ for R is very different to writing C++, every function must interface with R, taking and returning types R knows how to deal with.